# Ajax Checkbox with form data

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I am really confused how i managed these things.Please look at the attached image.See the right panel area.

Starting from first, package name is coming from last page; let's say page1.php. Now assume this attached image is page2.php.I am able to grab the selected checkbox values from left hand side and it is posting on right hand side.See i have checked the video checkbox.I have used jquery for that.

Problem 1 if i refresh the page values disappear except package value.I want the all checkbox value from right panel whatever user checked and post it to page3.php for further usage.I dont think jquery will do.I used the ajax post but cant able to grab values from below code.kindly help him regarding this.

Image link  http://s7.postimage.org/3zbf1ucwb/image.jpg

```
  function refreshPrices() {

       var beg=<?php echo isset($beg) ? $beg : 0 ?>;
       var inte=<?php echo isset($int) ? $int : 0 ?>;
       var advn=<?php echo isset($adv) ? $adv : 0 ?>;
       var currentTotalValue = 0;
        currentTotalValue = currentTotalValue + beg + inte + advn;
        $("#results div").each(function() {
            if (!isNaN(parseInt($(this).find("span").text().substring(1)))) {
                currentTotalValue += parseInt($(this).find("span").text().substring(1));
            }
        });


        $("#totalValue").text("$" + currentTotalValue)

    }

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#1').click(function() {
            //var row = $(this);
            if (($(this).attr('checked')) == 'checked') {
                $('#result').append("-PDF Document <html><span style=float:right>$100</span></html>");
            }
            else {
                $('#result').text("");
            }

            refreshPrices()


        });

        $('#2').click(function() {
            if (($(this).attr('checked')) == 'checked') {
                $('#result2').append("-Video <html><span style=float:right>$200</span></html> ");
            }
            else {
                $('#result2').text("");
            }

            refreshPrices()
        });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).attr('checked')` returns true or false, not 'checked', so you need to do :

```
if ( $(this).prop(':checked') ) { --- }
```

or just

```
if ( this.checked ) {
    $('#result').append("-PDF Document <html><span style=float:right>$100</span></html>");
}
```

Also, you should'nt be using just a number as an ID, change it to `#a1` etc. and you do realize that `<html>` tags are the start and end of the document, and appending them to an element inside the DOM does really seem like a great idea.

Comment: Sounds good,but my main question how to grab the value and post it to page3.php

Comment: It's hard to read the question, it's just one long line, and I'm still not sure I get it? You'd like to keep the values from the checkboxes even after you load a new page, if so you'll need to store the values in cookies or localstorage, add them as a querystring, or do something similar on the serverside.